# Distribution of the norm of a multivariate normal distributed random variable

Tags: probability, random-walk

As a part of a project, I would like to know what the distribution is of the absolute distance people traveled on a particular moment of the day (in comparison to their home). I think it would be best modeled with a simple random walk $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. The central limit theorem gives $n^{-1/2}S_n \to Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,(1/2)I_2)$ with $I_2$ the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. So, basically, my question is (using the Euclidean norm):

> What is the distribution of $\| Z \|$, where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,(1/2)I_2)$?

I tried to calculate this distribution by integration along a circle with radius $r$. I get the density function
\begin{align*} f(r) = 2r\exp(-r^2).   \end{align*}
This gives $f(0)=0$. However, my intuition says otherwise: the most likely place a random walk will be after a some time, is at the origin. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my calculation for the density function. The multivariate normal distribution $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2^{-1}I_2)$ has the density function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by 
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi} \exp(-(x^2+y^2)).
\end{align*} 
Consider an $s > 0$. I used the parametrization function $s: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\theta \mapsto (r\cos\theta, r\sin \theta)$. The integral along the circle with radius $r > 0$ then becomes
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) \| s'(\theta) \| \ \text{d}\theta = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} r\exp(-r^2) \ \text{d}\theta = 2re^{-r^2}.
\end{align*}

I found one question similar to this one ([The distance distribution from the mean for an n-dimensional normal(Gaussian) distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218334/the-distance-distribution-from-the-mean-for-an-n-dimensional-normalgaussian-di)), but it is unanswered.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \Pr\left(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\le w\right) \\[10pt]
= {} &  \iint\limits_{\begin{smallmatrix} \text{disk of} \\[2pt] \text{radius } w\end{smallmatrix}} \frac 1 {2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \,d(x,y) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^w \frac 1 {2\pi} e^{-r^2/2} \Big( r\,dr\,d\theta\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & 2\pi \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^w e^{-r^2/2} r\,dr = \int_0^{w^2/2} e^{-u}\,du \\[10pt]
= {} & 1 - e^{-w^2/2}.
\end{align}

The density is then the derivative of that, which is $w\mapsto we^{-w^2/2}$ for $w\ge0$.

Comment: My intuition was false then. The most probable place for the random walk to be is at the origin. But the most likely distance to the origin of the random walk is not zero.